# SSH connection issue in Google Cloud Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm getting the below error while trying to connect with Browser-based SSH in Google cloud server

**Connection Failed
An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration.**

---

I tried to install the free SSL on Google Cloud server by using this link: https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-free-ssl-certificate-for-wordpress-on-google-cloud-click-to-deploy/

but after this command

```
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
chmod a+x certbot-auto
```

I got some error, and from that point, SSH is also not working.